# UITextView frame doesn't care about the attributes of its content

Tags: swift, attributes, uitextview, frame

I have a UITextView with an attributedText (containing font & lineSpacing to put lines closer).
I use the code below to determine the frame of the textView.

The problem is the `frame.height` is too much big, and doesn't seem to care about lineSpacing. It looks like the frame of the textView without specific lineSpacing.

Does anyone have an idea to fix this fail? Did I miss something?

```
//Attributes of textView         
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = -1.25

let textViewText = Data().text   

let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textViewText, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Medium", size: 14)!])   
attributedText.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedText.string.characters.count))

textView.attributedText = attributedText

...

//Determining the frame of textView in other method
let textViewText = Data().text    

let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()            
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = -1.25

let rect = NSString(string: textViewText).boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: view.bounds.size.width, height: view.bounds.size.height), 
                    options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin), 
                    attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Medium", size: 14)!, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle],
                    context: nil)
```

Comment: The lineSpacing value is always nonnegative according to the documentation.

Comment: You are right, I finally solved this by `lineHeightMultiple`, `maximumLineHeight` and `minimumLineHeight` instead of `lineSpacing`.